# Process IMSManifest.xml with XPath and C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am unfamiliar with XPath and I'm looking for guidance on simply selecting three values from a file: schemaversion, title and description.

The Xpath expression `//title/langstring` only matches the element value when I strip out the name spacing information from `<manifest>` and `<lom>`.

*What is the correct way to search the contents for these values?*

Unit test:

```
[Test]
public void TitleIsNotNull()
{
  var manifestManager = new ManifestManager("imsmanifest.xml");
  // Code which initializes object and calls GetTitle() is encapsulated.
  Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(manifestManager.Title);
}
```

System Under Test:

```
private string GetTitle()
{
  var document = XElement.Parse(_contents);
  const string XpathExpression = "//title/langstring";
  return (string)document.XPathSelectElement(XpathExpression);
}
```

_contents (excerpted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2
  imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd 
  http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd 
  http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" 
  xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" 
  version="1.0"
  identifier="ExampleIdGoesHere">
  <metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>1.2</schemaversion>
    <lom xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1
               imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1">
        <general>
            <title>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Example title goes here.</langstring>
            </title>
            <description>
                <langstring xml:lang="x-none">Example description goes here.</langstring>
            </description>
        </general>
    </lom>
  </metadata>
```

## Tweaked Code Based on Steven Doggart's solution

**//Revised**

```
private string GetTitle()
{
  var xmlReader = GetXmlReader();
  var document = XElement.Load(xmlReader);
  var xmlNamespaceManager = GetXmlNamespaceManager(xmlReader);
  const string XpathExpression = "//y:title/y:langstring";
  return (string)document.XPathSelectElement(XpathExpression, xmlNamespaceManager);
}
```

**//Private Helpers**

```
    private XmlReader GetXmlReader()
    {
        var contents = new StringReader(_contents);
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(contents);
        return xmlReader;
    }

    private XmlNamespaceManager GetXmlNamespaceManager(XmlReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (xmlReader.NameTable != null)
        {
            var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlReader.NameTable);
            xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2");
            xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("y", "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1");
            return xmlNamespaceManager;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the element you are trying to select actually belongs to a certain namespace, but you are not specifying the namespace when you select it.  The `title` and `langstring` elements both belong to the default namespace.  In the XML document, the default namespace is defined as `"http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2"`.  With XPath, there is no way to specify a default namespace.  If you do not provide a namespace, it always assumes you mean no namespace at all.  Therefore, to select that element, you will have to explicitly provide the namespace, like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2");
const string XpathExpression = "//x:title/x:langstring";
return (string)document.XPathSelectElement(XpathExpression, namespaceManager);
```

The trick, however, is getting the `XmlNameTable` to give to the `XmlNamespaceManager`.  Unfortunately, the `XElement` class does not provide a way to get the `XmlNameTable` for the document, so your best bet would be to load it via an `XmlReader`, which can provide that, like this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(_contents));
XElement document = XElement.Load(reader);
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2");
const string XpathExpression = "//x:title/x:langstring";
return (string)document.XPathSelectElement(XpathExpression, namespaceManager);
```

Alternatively, you could use `XmlDocument` which is slightly easier when dealing with namespaces.  Or, you could also choose to use LINQ to select the element instead of XPath.

Comment: Steven I'm not sure what I've bungled but the value is coming back null and failing my test.

Comment: In order to make it work on my end, I had to also remove the `schemalocation` attributes.  Try that and see if it fixes it for you.  If so, that's where the second part of your problem is.

Comment: I was able to add a new namespace declaration `xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("y", "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1");` to find the elements nested under the `<lom>` element.  I revised my question to include your fix-ups and I've accepted your answer.  Thank you.